# How can I use custom format to remove %

Tags: ms-access-2010

I have a format `0.00%` and `1.99%` but would like to convert to `0.00` and `1.99`. I have used `Format(number, "#,##0.00")` but no luck. Can someone please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the column values contain the char `%` this means that its data type is `TEXT`, so you can use [`REPLACE()`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/replace-function-6acf209b-01b7-4078-b4b8-e0a4ef67d181):

```
REPLACE(number, '%', '')
```

or if needed:

```
TRIM(REPLACE(number, '%', ''))
```

and if you want it as a number use also [`VAL()`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/val-function-e5e1f21b-22f9-41c9-bd0a-fe55b767f603):

```
VAL(REPLACE(number, '%', ''))
```

Comment: Or also take the substring of length-1

Comment: @B.Go this would need another function call.

Comment: Yes, to `left()`. As trim an,d replace also do (take a function call), no?

Comment: Replace in this case does what Left and Len would do.